# Google Cloud SGX

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform

Google Cloud Platform current has Intel Skylake processors and they support SGX. However, in order to use SGX, the BIOS needs to have SGX enabled also. Is there any way to enable SGX on Google Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, SGX is currently disabled on the Google Cloud Platform. As per the following [article](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/Introducing-Asylo-an-open-source-framework-for-confidential-computing.html),

> Google is exploring future backends based on AMD Secure Encryption Virtualization (SEV) technology, Intel® Software Guard Extensions (Intel® SGX), and other industry-leading hardware technologies that could support the same rebuild-and-run portability.

this is likely to be supported in the future. However, you can use the open-source framework "Asylo" to develop enclave applications that explicitly supports SGX.